# When i press power key to lock the screen, onResume is called after onPause

Tags: android, android-activity

When i press power key in my android game, the activity's `onPaused` get called as expected, but `onResume` is also get called after that, which cause the game music playing with lock screen turned on. And the screen is not turned off as expected.

The `screenOrientation` is set to `landscape`, and `configChanges="screenSize|fontScale|orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard"`.

I've searched for hours on the google and android documentation, but got nothing. Hope someone can enlighten me.

Comment: You should post some code, especially what's happening in onCreate/onPause/onResume, e.g. wakelocks etc.

Comment: I have seen something similar.  It was related to what I was doing in onPause to do with various wakeLocks.

Comment: Thanks, it do have something to do with my acquire/release wake lock, when i remove those calls, this problem disappears.